# Upper bound for sum of binomials $\sum_{k=0}^{d}{N-1\choose k}$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, binomial-coefficients, factorial

I am interested to find a proof for the following upper bound.

$$\sum_{k=0}^{d}\begin{pmatrix}N-1\\k\end{pmatrix} \leq \frac{2N^d}{d!}$$

for $N\geq 3d$. I have tried to bound the sum by $(d+1)$ times the maximum of the binomial (attained at $k = d$), which yields the upper bound $2N^{d+1}/d!$ (worse by a factor of $N$). However, I could not find a proof for the above inequality.

Any ideas on how to start the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True when $d = 0$.

Suppose true up to $d-1$ for $d \geq 1$.  Need
\begin{align*}
\frac{(N-1)!}{(N-d-1)!\ d!} &\leq \frac{2N^d}{d!} - \frac{2N^{d-1}}{(d-1)!}  \\
    &= \left(1 - \frac{d}{N} \right) \frac{2N^d}{d!}  \text{,}
\end{align*}
simplifying to
$$  \frac{(N-1)!}{(N-d-1)!} \leq \left(1 - \frac{d}{N} \right) 2 N^d  \text{.}  $$
The left-hand side is less than or equal to $N^d$ and (using the constraint between $N$ and $d$), the right-hand side is greater than or equal to $\frac{4}{3}N^d$.

(If the displayed inequality is a little mysterious, ask how each side of your inequality changes going from $d-1$ to $d$.  In detail, write out \begin{align*}
k &= 0 &&:& \frac{(N-1)!}{(N-1)!\ 0!} &\leq \frac{2N^0}{0!}  \\
k &= 1 &&:& \frac{(N-1)!}{(N-1-1)!\ 1!} &\leq \frac{2N^1}{1!} - \frac{2N^0}{0!} \\
  &  &&&  &\vdots  \\
  &  &&& \frac{(N-1)!}{(N-k-1)!\ k!} &\leq \frac{2N^k}{k!} - \frac{2N^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}  \\
  &  &&& &\vdots  \\
k &= d &&:& \frac{(N-1)!}{(N-d-1)!\ d!} &\leq \frac{2N^d}{d!} - \frac{2N^{d-1}}{(d-1)!}
\end{align*}
Summing the left-hand sides gives the sum you ask about.  Summing the right-hand sides telescopes to the term you want to compare with.)

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful proof.

Comment: I guess it should say "The left-hand side is less than or equal to $N^d/d!$ ..." and "the right-hand side is greater than or equal to $\frac{4}{3}\,N^d/d!$. I think you are missing the $d!$.

Comment: @iom10  : Oh, right, meant to cancel those from both sides.  Fixed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A different proof that works for $N>3d$. Using [$(8.17.4)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.17.E4) and [$(8.17.5)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.17.E5), your sum may be re-expresssed in terms of the incomplete beta function:
$$
2^{N - 1} I_{1/2} (N - d - 1,d + 1) = 2^{N - 1} \frac{{\Gamma (N)}}{{\Gamma (N - d - 1)d!}}\int_0^{1/2} {t^{N - d - 2} (1 - t)^d \mathrm{d}t} .
$$
Now
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{1/2} {t^{N - d - 2} (1 - t)^d \mathrm{d}t} & = \int_0^{1/2} {t^{N - 2d - 2} t^d (1 - t)^d \mathrm{d}t} \\ & \le \frac{1}{{2^{2d} }}\int_0^{1/2} {t^{N - 2d - 2} \mathrm{d}t}  = \frac{1}{{2^{N - 1} }}\frac{1}{{N - 2d - 1}}.
\end{align*}
So your sum is at most
$$
\frac{1}{{N - 2d - 1}}\frac{{\Gamma (N)}}{{\Gamma (N - d - 1)d!}} = \frac{{N - d - 1}}{{N - 2d - 1}}\frac{{\Gamma (N)}}{{\Gamma (N - d)d!}} \le 2\frac{{\Gamma (N)}}{{\Gamma (N - d)d!}} \le \frac{{2N^d }}{{d!}}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your help :) Took me some time to understand the full glory of this proof.

Comment: You are welcome.